# Cannot read property "from" of undefined

Tags: charts, google-visualization, joomla2.5

["You need show full error, where does it happen, etc."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR1VN.png)

There is a .php file (view) on Joomla 2.5.1 with a code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function drawMachines() {
        
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Machine');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Printed');
        data.addRow(['LP-3000', 69174.8542]);
        data.addRow(['MPS', 74595.0154]);
        data.addRow(['MPS-2', 85626.7536]);
        data.addRow(['Digicon', 650.1061]);
        data.addRow(['Indigo-4500', 17630.4017]);
        data.addRow(['KDO-508', 15414.495]);
        data.addRow(['MP', 0.0237]);

        var options = {
            'title': 'For machines'
            ,'titleTextStyle': {fontSize: '12'}
            ,'legend': {position: 'none'}
            ,'enableInteractivity': false
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('com_fp_infopanel_manufacture_machines'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
</script>


<div class="com_fp_infopanel_manufacture">
    <div id="com_fp_infopanel_manufacture_machines" class="com_fp_infopanel_manufacture_machines"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I get an error: "Cannot read property "from" of undefined".

Has anyone encountered such an error?
Perhaps someone can suggest what is the reason?

The view-source code:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 ie6" lang="ru"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie7" lang="ru"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 ie8" lang="ru"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="ru"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
      <base href="http://infopanel.fleksoprint.ru/index.php" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="50; URL='index.php?option=com_fp_infopanel&amp;view=sales&amp;layout=0'; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="generator" content="J!Blank Template by Joomla-book.ru" />
  <title>Flexo Print</title>
  <link href="/templates/jblank/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/com_fp_infopanel/site/css/manufacture.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/jblank/css/base.css?1346224085" type="text/css" media="all"  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/jblank/css/grid.css?1346224085" type="text/css" media="all"  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/jblank/css/_styles.css?1346224085" type="text/css" media="all"  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/mod_fp_infopanel/css/shipping.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/mod_fp_infopanel/css/birthday.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/templates/jblank/js/libs/jquery.min.js?v=1.7.1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/templates/jblank/js/libs/modernizr.min.js?1346224085" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/templates/jblank/js/libs/jquery.tools.js?1346224085" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/templates/jblank/js/libs/jquery-ui.min.js?1346224085" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/templates/jblank/js/libs/jquery.mousewheel.min.js?1346224085" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/templates/jblank/js/libs/jquery.smoothdivscroll.min.js?1346224085" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/mod_coolclock/assets/js/excanvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/mod_coolclock/assets/js/coolclock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/mod_coolclock/assets/js/moreskins.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        
        <div class="grid_2 content">
            <div class="module module-left module-header "><h3 class="module-header">Часы</h3><div class="module-content">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function mod_coolclock132_date_refresh()
    {
        var months = [];
        months.push('Января');
        months.push('Февраля');
        months.push('Марта');
        months.push('Апреля');
        months.push('Мая');
        months.push('Июня');
        months.push('Июля');
        months.push('Августа');
        months.push('Сентября');
        months.push('Октября');
        months.push('Ноября');
        months.push('Декабря');

        var weekdays = [];
        weekdays.push('Воскресенье');
        weekdays.push('Понедельник');
        weekdays.push('Вторник');
        weekdays.push('Среда');
        weekdays.push('Четверг');
        weekdays.push('Пятница');
        weekdays.push('Суббота');

        var today = new Date();
        var date = '<h4>' + weekdays[today.getDay()] + ', ' + today.getDate() + ' ' + months[today.getMonth()] + ' ' + today.getFullYear();
        $('#mod_coolclock_date132').html(date);
    }

    window.setInterval(mod_coolclock132_date_refresh, 60000);
    mod_coolclock132_date_refresh();
});
</script>

<div style="text-align: center; border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px; border-style: ridge; border-width: 3px;">
    <div><canvas id="clock132" class="CoolClock:swissRail:68::+4"></canvas></div>
    <div id="mod_coolclock_date132"></div>
</div></div></div><div class="module module-left module-header "><h3 class="module-header">Время прихода</h3><div class="module-content">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mod_fp_infopanel_birthday_employees135").smoothDivScroll({
            mousewheelScrolling: false,
            manualContinuousScrolling: false,
            hotSpotScrolling: false,
            autoScrollingMode: "always",
            autoScrollingDirection: "endlesslooptop"
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="mod_fp_infopanel_birthday_employees135" class="mod_fp_infopanel_birthday_employees">
    <div class="scrollWrapper">
        <div class="scrollableArea">
            <!--                <p style="clear: both;"/>
                    <div style="background-color: #2F6309;width:32px;height:12px;margin-top:6px;margin-left:5px;"></div>
                    <div style="color: #FFFFFF;padding:4px;font-weight:bold;font-size:10px;text-align:center;position:relative;margin-top:-17px;margin-bottom:-2px;">Авг</div>
                    <div style="color: #2F6309;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.3em;width:42px;text-align:center;">18</div>
                </div>-->
                
                
            <p class="mod_fp_infopanel_birthday_employee">09:46:18 - Кудинов  Сергей Борисович</p>
                <p style="clear: both;"/>
            <!--                <p style="clear: both;"/>
                    <div style="background-color: #2F6309;width:32px;height:12px;margin-top:6px;margin-left:5px;"></div>
                    <div style="color: #FFFFFF;padding:4px;font-weight:bold;font-size:10px;text-align:center;position:relative;margin-top:-17px;margin-bottom:-2px;">Авг</div>
                    <div style="color: #2F6309;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.3em;width:42px;text-align:center;">18</div>
                </div>-->
                
                
            <p class="mod_fp_infopanel_birthday_employee">09:36:04 - Логинов Роман Викторович</p>
                <p style="clear: both;"/>
            <!--                <p style="clear: both;"/>
                    <div style="background-color: #2F6309;width:32px;height:12px;margin-top:6px;margin-left:5px;"></div>
                    <div style="color: #FFFFFF;padding:4px;font-weight:bold;font-size:10px;text-align:center;position:relative;margin-top:-17px;margin-bottom:-2px;">Авг</div>
                    <div style="color: #2F6309;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.3em;width:42px;text-align:center;">18</div>
                </div>-->
                
                
            <p class="mod_fp_infopanel_birthday_employee">09:11:28 - Мазин  Александр Петрович</p>
                <p style="clear: both;"/>
            <!--                <p style="clear: both;"/>
                    <div style="background-color: #2F6309;width:32px;height:12px;margin-top:6px;margin-left:5px;"></div>
                    <div style="color: #FFFFFF;padding:4px;font-weight:bold;font-size:10px;text-align:center;position:relative;margin-top:-17px;margin-bottom:-2px;">Авг</div>
                    <div style="color: #2F6309;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.3em;width:42px;text-align:center;">18</div>
                </div>-->
                
                
            <p class="mod_fp_infopanel_birthday_employee">09:05:50 - Семенова Дарья Витальевна</p>
                <p style="clear: both;"/>
                    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div></div>
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="grid_8 content">
            <div class="module module-middle module-header "><h3 class="module-header">Показатели компании</h3><div class="module-content"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dateInFuture(days)
    {
        var now = new Date();
        now.setDate( now.getDate() + days );
        return now;
    }
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Машина');
        data.addColumn('date', 'Загрузка');
        data.addRows([['MPS', dateInFuture(5.3083425954183)]]);
        data.addRows([['MPS-2', dateInFuture(10.435140861034)]]);
        data.addRows([['LP-3000', dateInFuture(3.3856865581936)]]);
        data.addRows([['Indigo-4500', dateInFuture(0.019926592893071)]]);

        var options = {
                title: 'Загрузка печатного оборудования',
                titleTextStyle: { fontSize: '12'},
                legend: {position: 'none'},
                hAxis: {format: 'dd MMM', minValue: new Date()},
                enableInteractivity: false
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_load136'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
</script>
<div class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_container">
<div id="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_kpi136" class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_kpi">
<dl class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_Bar">
    <dt class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarLabel">ВП</dt>
    <dd class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarScale">
        <div class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarFilled" style="width: 40.243306389056%;">40.2%<strong>&nbsp;</strong></div>
        <div class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarAnotation">101 164,83 EUR. / 251 383,00 EUR.</div>
    </dd>
    <dt class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarLabel">Отгрузка</dt>
    <dd class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarScale">
        <div class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarFilled" style="width: 40.930513139422%;">40.9%<strong>&nbsp;</strong></div>
        <div class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarAnotation">250 437,85 EUR. / 611 861,00 EUR.</div>
    </dd>
    <dt class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarLabel">Произведено</dt>
    <dd class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarScale">
        <div class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarFilled" style="width: 42.998597671693%;">43.0%<strong>&nbsp;</strong></div>
        <div class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarAnotation">263 091,65 EUR. / 611 861,00 EUR.</div>
    </dd>
    <dt class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarLabel">Склад</dt>
    <dd class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarPanel">
        <div class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_BarValueText">47 306,65 EUR.</div>
    </dd>
</dl>
</div>
</div>
<div id="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_load136" class="mod_fp_infopanel_shipping_load"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div></div><div class="module module-middle module-header "><div class="module-content">

<div class="custom"  >
    <hr /></div>
</div></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});

    // Разбивка по машинам
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function drawMachines() {
        
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Машина');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Отпечатано');
        data.addRow(['LP-3000', 69174.8542]);
        data.addRow(['MPS', 74595.0154]);
        data.addRow(['MPS-2', 85626.7536]);
        data.addRow(['Digicon', 650.1061]);
        data.addRow(['Indigo-4500', 17630.4017]);
        data.addRow(['KDO-508', 15414.495]);
        data.addRow(['МП', 0.0237]);

        var options = {
            'title': 'По машинам'
            ,'titleTextStyle': {fontSize: '12'}
            ,'legend': {position: 'none'}
            ,'enableInteractivity': false
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('com_fp_infopanel_manufacture_machines'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });

    // Разбивка по сменам
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function drawShifts() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Бригада');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Отпечатано');
        data.addRow(['Катайкин', 48949.1127]);
        data.addRow(['Владимиров', 55795.0403]);
        data.addRow(['Шурыгин', 56640.1172]);
        data.addRow(['Ломакин', 68120.6211]);
        data.addRow(['Кононенко', 4385.4825]);
        data.addRow(['Спиридонов', 8308.4379]);
        data.addRow(['Станчев', 5418.9761]);
        data.addRow(['Галушкин', 8535.9824]);
        data.addRow(['Голев', 2884.7224]);
        data.addRow(['Салтыков', 3993.7902]);
        data.addRow(['Контракт', 59.3432]);

        var options = {
            'title': 'По бригадам'
            ,'titleTextStyle': {fontSize: '12'}
            ,'legend': {position: 'none'}
            ,'enableInteractivity': false
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('com_fp_infopanel_manufacture_shifts'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });

</script>


<div class="com_fp_infopanel_manufacture">
    <div id="com_fp_infopanel_manufacture_machines" class="com_fp_infopanel_manufacture_machines"></div>
    <div id="com_fp_infopanel_manufacture_shifts" class="com_fp_infopanel_manufacture_shifts"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

        </div>
        <div class="grid_2 content">
            
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

                    <div class="modules-bottom content grid_12">
                <div class="module module-bottom module-grid grid_12 "><div class="module-content">

<div class="custom"  >
    <p><a href="https://clck.yandex.ru/redir/dtype=stred/pid=7/cid=1228/*https://yandex.ru/pogoda/38" target="_blank"><img src="https://info.weather.yandex.net/38/2_white.ru.png?domain=ru" border="0" alt="Яндекс.Погода" /><img src="https://clck.yandex.ru/click/dtype=stred/pid=7/cid=1227/*https://img.yandex.ru/i/pix.gif" border="0" alt="" width="1" height="1" /></a></p></div>
</div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        
        
            </div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need show full error, where does it happen, etc.

Comment: Thanx. Added a screenshot with an error to the post.

Comment: At which line does error happen?

Comment: The line ".draw(...)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved this way:

```
...
google.charts.load('44', ...
...
```

Look at: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#official-releases

Comment: You may award your own answer the green tick to mark this question resolved.  If you are doing Joomla development, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.